# Show that $f(x) = \sqrt{x^3}+3$ for $\{x≥0 \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is differentiable and find its derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

I'd like to find out if the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x^3}+3$ is differentiable for $\{x≥0 \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and if it is, then find it's derivative.

First I "simplified" the function $f(x)= (\sqrt {x^3}+3)^\frac{1}{2}$ and used the difference quotient to show that $f(x)$ is differentiable for $x>0$.

$$\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \frac{(\sqrt{x^3}+3)- \left(\sqrt{x_0^3}+3 \right)}{x-x_0}= \frac{\sqrt{x^3}- \sqrt{x_0^3}}{x-x_0}$$

We know that $x^3-x_0^3=\left(\sqrt{x^3} - \sqrt{x_0^3}\right)\left(\sqrt{x^3} + \sqrt{x_0^3}\right)$, therefore:

$$ \implies  \frac{\left(\sqrt{x^3} - \sqrt{x_0^3} \right)}{\left({x^3} - \sqrt{x_0^3}\right)\left({x^3} + \sqrt{x_0^3}\right)} = \frac{1}{\left({x^3} + \sqrt{x_0^3}\right)}$$

Additionally, we show that $\lim_\limits{x\to x_0}\left({x^3} + \sqrt{x_0^3}\right) = 2\sqrt {x_0^3}$ and therefore:

$$\implies f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt {x_0^3}} $$

Therefore when $\{x>0 \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, $f(x)$ is differentiable and now I'd have to show that $f(x)$ is differentiable for $x=0$. I do this by using the difference quotient.

$$\lim _\limits{x \to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}=\lim _\limits{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x^3}+3 }{x}=\frac{\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \sqrt {x^3}+3}{\lim_\limits{x \to 0}x}$$

Since I get a situation where I would have to divide by $0$ I can't continue but in my exercise sheet it says that its $∞$ and I don't understand why. From the looks of it, I made a mistake somewhere or I have some understanding gap.

Comment: Oh snap. That seems to be a writing mistake. Sorry about that. Yeah now that I look back at that, I'm not sure how I can even use that fact to help with the proof.

Comment: Chain rule maybe? Then treat $x=0$ apart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start off fine, somewhere your algebra goes a little wonky.

You are not quite explict with that algebra.  So, I am having a had time putting my finger on the error.

This is how I would do it.

$f'(a) = \lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {(\sqrt{x^3}+3) - (\sqrt{a^3}+3)}{x-a}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {\sqrt{x^3} - \sqrt{a^3}}{x-a}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {(\sqrt{x^3} - \sqrt{a^3})(\sqrt{x^3} + \sqrt{a^3})}{(x-a)(\sqrt{x^3} + \sqrt{a^3})}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {x^3 - a^3}{(x-a)(\sqrt{x^3} + \sqrt{a^3})}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)}{(x-a)(\sqrt{x^3} + \sqrt{a^3})}\\
f'(a) =\frac {3a^2}{2a\sqrt{a}}\\
f'(a) =\frac {3\sqrt a}{2}\\
f'(0) =0\\
$